# Is noexec a standard setting for home?

Tags: permissions, mount, security, home

I have been told that noexec is a standard setting for /home folder for development environments. Can someone provide some references?

Using noexec on /home prevents applications like IDEs, editors, etc. from working properly as expected.

Comment: Which standard are you referring to? [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s08.html) doesn't seem to mention anything about it. Maybe you should ask the source of the statement for sources backing it up rather than random folks on the internet?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you (or they) referring to? Distributions may have different defaults.

Comment: Rhel8. I check nodes in cloud providers, as well the official docker image and they dont have noexec separate settings for home. Unfortunately the source is not collaborative. That is why I revert back to the community and my own contacts. The source says it is unorthodox to not use noexec

Comment: The UK National Cyber Security Centre for instance recommends it (see [their post-install hardening script for Ubuntu](https://github.com/ukncsc/Device-Security-Guidance-Configuration-Packs/blob/1f4f8eca928fdfcbe7c09d4c5300179f2576e093/Linux/UbuntuLTS/Ubuntu-LTS-post-install.sh#L89) for instance), and IIRC the Centre for Internet Security as well (same for all temp areas), but those are more intended for systems where regular users have no administrative rights and do more office-like work than development. Even on /tmp, noexec tends to break many things.

Comment: Thanks, and what is applicable in case the node is a development machine shared by 5 developers who need to run their IDEs but the noexec breaks them?

Comment: _"...a standard setting..."_ -- Standards are fun. There are so many to choose from.

Comment: for development, I'd be more worried about if they need to run the program they're developing.

Comment: The libraries are developed and running/tested in a separate drive/folder than home.

Comment: It depends on how far the organization wants to go to lock down their developmental code. One extreme case might be that the developer's computer is used just as a SSH terminal, and all code is kept on well-secured servers and tested on autobuilders outside devs' direct control. On the other hand, if the developers are expected to incorporate the newest bleeding-edge components and experiment on their own, and any test material does not include anything like financial, identity or health information, some organizations might give trusted developers root access to their workstations.

Comment: @telcoM I know one that was even more extreme: SSH terminal (to a Solaris box IIIRC) that could only be accessed from a Windows jump server that was itself accessible only via RDP over a VPN. Financial, in this case.

Comment: @user1221647, well, yes, then they don't _need_ execute permissions in $HOME as such, but then again any Bad Stuff that could be done through self-made executables (by the user or a cracker using their account) could be done through that separate directory that does allow execution. It's a bit unclear IMO what the gain would be unless you disable execution everywhere. And if you go there, you might want to consider interpreters like Perl too...

Comment: @user1221647 *I have been told that noexec is a standard setting for /home...*  You should first get some popcorn, then tell whoever told you that about [Python's ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) - where you can write a Python script **that can make any call offered by your OS**.  Thus doing anything possible for your user on your system despite any efforts such as `noexec`.  They'll probably want to delete Python from your system - and thus break it.  :-)

Comment: I'd pay little attention to what the UKNSC, or any other national body, says about security... They rarely know what they're talking about

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I have been told that `noexec` is a standard setting for /home folder for development environments.

That's an opinion I've not seen anywhere else ever.

No, there's nothing "standard" about it. Standards imply standardization and I've not seen ISO standards or RFCs talking about any flags specific to `/home`.

In fact most Linux distros don't even (offer to) allocate `/home` as a separate partition and if it's not then you cannot use any specific mount options with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Fedora Desktop defaults to a separate /home partition/subvolume especially if using btrfs. In any case, no noexec flag is applied.

Comment: "Standards imply standardization" -- there are *de facto* standards that don't require this. A more common term for this is "best practices".

Comment: The standard installers for RedHat-famiily Linuxes offer a built-in option for putting `/home` on its own partition.  That's a sufficient proportion of the installed base that "*most Linux distros don't even (offer to) allocate `/home` as a separate partition*" is misleading at best.  But with that said, I agree that mounting `/home` with the `noexec` flag is not a thing I've ever heard of, nor something that I think would be desirable for many environments.

Comment: Most distro-supplied `.profile` / `.bash_profile` scripts add `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` if it exists; that's fairly strong evidence that this historically hasn't been standard practice.

Answer (score 19):

`noexec` is useless as a direct security countermeasure except in environments that are very restricted. If you want to execute a file that's in a `noexec` filesystem, you can:

- Run it directly with the dynamic linker (e.g. `/lib/ld.so myfile`) if it's a dynamically linked executable.
- Run it directly with the interpreter (e.g. `/bin/sh myscript`) if it's a script.
- Copy it to another filesystem that allows executable files (e.g. `cp myfile /tmp && /tmp/myfile`) if there is one where you can write.

If you allow someone to run programs on a computer, they'll be able to run programs on a computer… And for a *developer* machine, you do expect them to run programs. Not only that, you expect them to run programs that nobody has validated (because that exact program didn't exist five minutes ago).

`noexec` is slightly useful as a **passive** security countermeasure, in that it does protect against malware that tries to download a file and execute it. Of course the malware can easily work around that, but only if the developer of the malware thought about it. Most malware is unaffected (in particular, malware that targets browsers is unaffected since it just runs in the context of the browser). So it's weak protection against a rare threat. It's not worth the bother.

So `noexec` on `/home` is of extremely little use. And for a developer, it's really disruptive. For example, it breaks a lot of library management programs. So it's a bad idea.

Even on systems that are more locked down because the users only need to run a few specific programs, it is not a common setup at all.

Comment: Indeed, it adds very little value, especially cos in our case the machines have no internet access at all.

Comment: +1 Re: option 1, Is the viability of `/lib/ld.so myfile`: a Linuxism, or is that generally true?  On FreeBSD, `/libexec/ld-elf.so.1 myfile` returns `ld-elf.so.1: myfile: mmap of data failed: Permission denied`.  Is there another hack I can try to test circumvention of `noexec`?

Comment: @JimL. Not really a linuxism, but something that may or may not work on a given kernel depending on how it's configured. Mapping executable pages that aren't from an executable file has to work in order for just-in-time compilers to work. This is something you generally want on a workstation that runs a modern web browser, but not on a typical server. There are probably harderning patches that make it not work on Linux, and I'd expect that there's a way to make it work on FreeBSD but I don't know how.

Answer (score 8):

"The libraries are developed and running/tested in a separate drive/folder than home. "

That's it then. It's just dumb and bad.

The point of noexec was originally to set it on nontrusted media so suid programs don't work. We also got nosuid and nodev for the same reason.

But now in this century people are pressing noexec into a purpose it was not designed for; that is pressing for giving users no abilty to run foreign binaries (including binaries they install). This is pointless on a normal system because there's enough stuff in `/usr/bin` to make hash of everything (at a glance: `bochs`, `dd`, `ex`, `gdb`, `hexedit`, `m4`, `tar`, excluding the fact that if normal things like `lua`, `node`, `perl`, or `python` are present I need not run my own binary code); but can be an actual security defense on things like cell phones.

However; it doesn't work at all if the user has write permissions to any filesystem that doesn't have noexec. The admins are fighting a losing battle while demonstrating incompetence and breaking things while they're at it.

They probably have "prevent running unapproved software" as a checkbox somewhere. Let this sink in; by definition developers run unapproved software (the new changes they are developing), therefore they can run unapproved software and no manner of configuration changes can undo that.

Comment: "set it on nontrusted media" -- indeed, it's more useful pluggable devices like USB sticks.